# Error in installing/upgrading to python 3.4.3

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python-3.x, terminal, upgrade

I was attempting to install/upgrade from python 3.2 to 3.4.3, however many things have gone wrong. now, even if I

```
apt-get install python3
```

I get errors. Here is the terminal output

```
Setting up python-requests (0.8.2-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-requests.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-requests.postinst: pycompile: not found
dpkg: error processing python-requests (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Setting up python-gevent (0.13.6-1ubuntu1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-gevent.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-gevent.postinst: pycompile: not found
dpkg: error processing python-gevent (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Setting up python-qrencode (1.01-2build1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-qrencode.postinst: 5: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-qrencode.postinst: update-python-modules: not found
dpkg: error processing python-qrencode (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-requests
 python-gevent
 python-qrencode
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please, help me in resolving this.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get remove --purge python3 && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python3` to (probably) get back to a 'clean' state. Check python3 --version, you might be lucky and get python 3.4!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `sudo apt-get remove --purge python3 && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python3` to (probably) get back to a 'clean' state. Check `python3 --version` after that, you might be lucky and get python 3.4!

Comment: @Th'Ink-King can you explain what initially went wrong?

Comment: I'm unsure. I'm wondering if it happened when changing paths. Since now my applications which use python wont even load.

Comment: @Th'Ink-King What does `python3 --version` say, and `which python3`, and `which python`? Also which version of Ubuntu are you running? Check [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/565438/deleted-the-python-binary-and-cant-recover-using-apt-get-what-can-i-do) for possible helpful info.

Answer (score 2):

I accidentally deleted `python3.6` in `/usr/bin/`. When I reinstall it I got similar error message.

Then I tried the following commands and `python3.6` was installed:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge python3.6
sudo apt-get install -f --reinstall python3.6-minimal
```

I also tried `sudo apt-get install -f --reinstall python-minimal`, but it did not work.

Hope my experience is helpful for people in similar situations.